# Automatic sliding content inside a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a div with a set width and height, and I want the content inside to slide automatically (without hover or interaction from the user) after like so many seconds to reveal different content. What my actual goal is, I have boxes with an audio player and the notes of the generated content, and I want it to slide up down or left right whatever, to reveal the artist blabhalbalh. You can see what I'm talking about at [here](http://roseannebarr.tumblr.com).

Oh, silly me. A good example would be Windows Phone 7 live tiles, thats actually what I'm basing it off of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var swap = false;
    var w = 309;
    var h = 261;    
    var i = 0;
    var x = 0;
    var q = 1;
    var t;

    window.onload=function(){
        i = initPortfolio();
        setTimeout("portfolioRotate()",2000);
    }

    function initPortfolio(){
        $('.portfolio-item').each(function(index){i = i+1;});
        for(var n=1;n<=i;n=n+1){
            lpos = w * n - w;
            $('#item-'+n).css('left',lpos);
        }
        $('.offs').css('display','block');
        x =  i * w - w;
        return i;
    }
    function portfolioRotate(){
        swap = false;
        $('.portfolio-item').animate({left:'-='+w},6000,function(){
            nn = this.id.split("-")[1];
            if(q==nn && swap==false){
                $('#item-'+q).css('left',x);
                if(q<i){q=q+1}else{q=1};
                swap = true;
                u=setTimeout("portfolioRotate()",2000);
            }
        });
    }

        <div id="portfolio-container">
            <div class="portfolio-item" id="item-1"></div>
            <div class="portfolio-item" id="item-2"></div>
            <div class="portfolio-item" id="item-3"></div>
            <div class="portfolio-item offs" id="item-4"></div>
        </div>

    .offs{
        display:none;
    }
    #portfolio-container{
        width:927px;
        height:318px;
        margin-top:30px;
        position:relative;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
    .portfolio-item{
        width:309;
        padding-top:20px;
        position:absolute;
        height:100%;

    }
```

This might be terrible, but I just pulled it from something I was working on recently. Let me know if it isn't sliding, or needs explanation. using jQuery. there is probably a way better way to position the components initially with css.

Comment: have it working locally with the same code, sort of working at that same link, haven't used jsfiddle much, not sure if it will loop in timeout? just change it to ondomready and jquery 1.4.3

Comment: Sweet! can you have the first stay for a little while, it automatically goes to the next on load

Comment: yep, basically just call the portfolioRotate in the onload on a setTimeout, i'll change the code

Comment: Hey, can you visit my page and take a look at something? after 1 or 2 times it just keeps going... Can you reverse the animation, so that after it goes to 'cat', 'cat' goes back right and audio is brought in. i tried changing the algorithm or equation or whatever but i couldnt figure it out :( im not good at javascript.

Comment: yea, sure. i can give you the basic idea, at least. is it the link in your original post?

Comment: yep roseannebarr.tumblr.com Sorry for all the fuss, I just am learning javascript, and I am just very excited about this project.

Comment: hey, still around just really busy tonight

Comment: Oh, ok no prob! I just needed help with the problems from before. Audio just keep going after two rounds. Take your time! Thanks for all the help you have given meeee